# Add entry with the select-entry-modal-field

Tags: entries, plugins

So I have a 'Single' that uses entries from different 'Structures'. I can choose one or more entries with the fieldtype. But often I want to select an entry that is not created yet .. so I have to go back create that entry and then select it ..

It would be so much easier if I could just say "create a new entry" right there

[What I mean](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/hx75q90umu2wpr3/2014-11-16%20at%2017.18%202x.png)

Is there a plugin for that or anything ?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't, as far as I'm aware of, but have a look at the [Craft Plugin Library](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins). If you write your own, you might have a look at the following to see an example of a modal that craft does use:

```
var modal = Craft.createElementSelectorModal('Entry');
```

Try typing that into your console on any page in the CP.

Categories use a different kind of model when double clicking a category item that actually saves data, so might have a look at that as well.

Also, the [amcommand](https://github.com/am-impact/amcommand) plugin provides a nice modal command palette with a command to create entries that also might be worth checking out.